# How can I change the Joomla User Group of an existing user

Tags: joomla2.5

We'd like to change the user from "Registered" to a custom User Group "Customer" when they place an order.  I've been tinkering with the various ACL functions, but can't seem to find the way to make it happen.

I started with this, which I found on SO somewhere, but it seems to be dated because `$authorize->get_group_id` is not found, which makes me think the whole approach is wrong to begin with.

```
$user           = & JFactory::getUser();
$authorize      = & JFactory::getACL();
$newUsertype    = 'Customer';
$user->set('usertype', $newUsertype);
$user->set('gid', $authorize->get_group_id( '', $newUsertype, 'ARO' ));
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid simple....

```
$newUserGroup = 9;
$result = JUserHelper::addUserToGroup($user_id, $newUserGroup);
```